# Gateway Selection By Destination Ports

Tags: linux, gateway

I have found a similar question to mine, but it did not provide the answer I was looking for.

I work for a school with two distinct Internet connections, connected to two separate NAT routers. On my network I've configured a linux server that uses one of them as a default gateway. However, the default router is not connected directly to the Internet, and I can't configure port forwarding on it. The other one is, but that one is reserved for specific uses only, as the connection is much slower.

Both the routers are in the same network, one with the IP address 192.168.1.1, and one with the IP address 192.168.1.20. The default one which isn't connected directly to the Internet is 192.168.1.1.

My question is, if the default gateway is 192.168.1.1, how do I make the linux server use 192.168.1.20 as a gateway for responding to connections to specific ports when they come to one of the network interfaces (the one it does NAT to), like SSH, without setting permanent routes to 192.168.1.20?

I thank you in advance.

Comment: How is the server getting its network settings? Manually or via DHCP?

Comment: The default router has DHCP active while the non-default one doesn't, but the linux server has its interfaces set to manual. Its address is set to 192.168.1.254.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use Connection Tracking with Connection Marking, Multiple Routing Tables, and identify the 'upstream' router based on mac address.

If you can, split the 2 routers into different networks, even if they're still on the same Layer 2. This will make it easier (see below).

Basically, you need to:

1. Create 2 new routing tables, one with a default route via ISP1 (192.168.1.1) and one with a default route via ISP2 (192.168.1.20)
2. Change the default route in your main routing table to `throw`
3. Use iptables mangle table to mark connections dependant on their incoming router. In your instance, you're going to need to identify the mac address of each router to mark each connection properly.

iptables rules to mark each connection correctly:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m mac --mac aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa -j CONNMARK --set-mark 100
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m mac --mac bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb -j CONNMARK --set-mark 200
```

This is untested; I always use separate interfaces so I can us `-i eth1` and `-i eth2` instead of the `-m mac --mac` syntax.

Full information and all the gory details are too big for an answer here, but this is an excellent guide once you get your head around it: http://www.cyber.com.au/~twb/doc/dual-uplink.txt